# How best do I capture a service status on all my Windows Servers in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, service

Excuse my very limited knowledge of PowerShell commands but I basically want to get a service status report for all my servers. I know how to does this using a static list from a CSV file but ideally I would like to get it Dynamically each time.

I was looking at capturing this list to $servers as below:

**$servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*"} -Properties * | sort Name | ft Name -Wrap -Auto**

This works and produces the output ok but I want to follow this up with something like this but i cant seem to get the $servers working for this command?

**Get-Service -Computername $servers -Name wuauserv | Select-Object MachineName,Name,Displayname,Status | Sort-Object Status**

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO, please update your question with the error that you're getting with the command. what is the error message when you run the command?

Comment: Remove `ft Name -Wrap -Auto` from your command. `Format-*` cmdlets emit output objects whose sole purpose is to provide _formatting instructions_ to PowerShell's for-display output-formatting system. In short: only ever use `Format-*` cmdlets to format data _for display_, never for subsequent _programmatic processing_ - see the linked duplicate for more information.